# Installing Ubuntu as a main operating system

Tags: firmware

I am thinking of installing Ubuntu as a main / root operating system over the hardware like the title says.

I want to use Ubuntu, but everyone in my home network, and my friends all use windows. If I had Ubuntu, I wouldn't be able to share programs, files, information as efficiently...

Could a way around this be using a hypervisor / virtual machines within linux to host windows 7/10 that will share files, configure window home network settings?

Thanks in advance!

-Elias

Comment: You can still efficiently share files and information between Win and Ubuntu. There are alternative applications for most Windows software that is mostly able to read the same file formats, like e.g. LibreOffice instead of MS Office. And yes, of course you can set up a VM on your Ubuntu installation and run Windows inside it. You can set up a network bridge so that the VM appears as separate IP in the network and can be directly accessed from outside and you can set up a shared folder between guest and host system to exchange data locally.

Comment: Your question is tagged 'firmware'. Why? are you doing some microcontroller, embedded, etc. development?

Answer (score 1):

Me too faced this issue. I tried using the following to get through

1. Plex Media server

Plex has an Android app as well

2. Share a folder on Ubuntu PC ( you will need to install Samba )

Ubuntu and Windows networking somehow works together. I have Windows 7, Windows 10 and 16.04. And shared folder were visible on all PCs

All you have to do is use the Network icon in Ubuntu to see / fetch files from Windows PCs.